# How to remove index.php from url in codeigniter project

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, azure, azure-web-app-service

i tried to remove index.php from my url in codeigniter project hosted on azure server.if i manually removed index.php from url its showing "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable." following is my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

my config file

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://myapp.azurewebsites.net/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove index.php in Codeigniter URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115098/remove-index-php-in-codeigniter-url)

Comment: i used .htaccess as per above link suggested but it still showing "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: add "on Azure server" in your title and people wont be voting down so quickly

Answer (score 2):

Basically, in Azure Web App you could add **Default documents** via the Azure portal to achieve this.

1. In the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com/), open the blade for the web app.
2. Click **Application Settings**.
3. Add `index.php` to **Default documents** list.

[image]

BTW, Azure uses IIS (not Apache) to host your application, so the `.htaceess` file doesn't work in Azure Web App.